# How to transfer objects from an array of objects to another in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, c++17

I have an array of objects and I want to transfer the objects to another array. I've written the code bellow to do so but it did not work. It is basically a code where 52 card objects are created in one array and distributed between two arrays.Can anyone help me?

```
class card
{
public:
    string suit;
    string value;
    void setValue(string v);
    void setSuit(string s);
};
void card::setValue(string v)
    {
        value=v;
    }
void card::setSuit(string s)
    {
        suit=s;
    }
int main()
{
    string suites[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    string values[]={"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
    card cards[52];
    int i=0;
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<13;k++){
                cards[i].setSuit(suites[j]);
                cards[i].setValue(values[k]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    card player1_cards[26];
    card player2_cards[26];
    for(int a=0;a<52;a++){
        if(a%2==0){
                player1_cards[a]=cards[a];
        }
        else{
            player2_cards[a]=cards[a];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once `a` is equal-to-or-greather-than 26, `player1_cards` and `player2_cards` will be indexing past the end of the array.

Comment: What is not working? Which results do you receive?

Comment: Also I do not know if this is still a standard but naming classes with a capital letter might help you read the code a bit better. (Only an opinion but might help since you have a similar name).

Comment: "It did not work" is not a useful problem description. Although this one is an obvious bug, you need to keep in mind that once your bugs are not obvious, just describing them as "it did not work" will not allow for much progress to be made.

Comment: @Eljay thank you for the suggestion I was able to fix it this time.

Comment: @darclander: That's purely a matter of style; some people like uppercase name for classes, others don't. The boost library and the standard library, for example, don't use uppercase names at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every 2nd card to be added to `player1_cards` and the others to be added to `player2_cards` you can change your for-loop to:

```
for(int a=1;a<26;a++) {
    player1_cards[a] = cards[2*a];
    player2_cards[a] = cards[2*a-1];
}
```

As Eljay said in the comment to your question your index went past the end of the array.

I tried to compile the code myself and it seems like the following code splits the cards in to two different arrays, althought it is not random (which you might want to add if you are doing a card game).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class card
{
public:
    std::string suit;
    std::string value;
    void setValue(std::string v);
    void setSuit(std::string s);
    std::string printSV();
};
void card::setValue(std::string v)
    {
        value=v;
    }
void card::setSuit(std::string s)
    {
        suit=s;
    }

std::string card::printSV() {
    return suit + ": " + value + "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string suites[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    std::string values[]={"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
    card cards[52];
    int i=0;
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<13;k++){
                cards[i].setSuit(suites[j]);
                cards[i].setValue(values[k]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    card player1_cards[26];
    card player2_cards[26];
    for(int a=1;a<26;a++){
        player1_cards[a] = cards[2*a];
        player2_cards[a] = cards[2*a-1];
// prints the suite and value for each card in player1's and player2's hand.
        std::cout << player1_cards[a].printSV();
        std::cout << player2_cards[a].printSV();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `Suite: Value` for each of the cards in `cards[52]`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Eljay notes, you are trying to access elements past the end of the arrays. If you were to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your program, you would see this.

However, this is also a lesson for you to be careful of writing raw loops, with a lot of "magic-number" indices, and prefer using pre-existing patterns from the libraries (especially std::algorithm) when relevant. See [this talk by Sean Parent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA) about this general principle.

Specifically, you could have written your program as follows:

```
#include <range/v3/view.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct card {
    std::string suite;
    std::string value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const card& c)
{
    return os << c.value << " of " << c.suite; 
}

int main()
{
    using namespace ranges;

    std::array suites {"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    std::array values {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
    auto cards = 
        views::cartesian_product(suites, values) | 
        views::transform([](const auto& suite_and_value) -> card { 
            return { std::get<0>(suite_and_value), std::get<1>(suite_and_value) };
        });
    auto num_players { 2 };
    auto player1_cards =
        cards | views::stride(num_players);
    auto player2_cards = 
        cards | views::drop(1) | views::stride(num_players);
    std::cout << "Player 1 got: " << player1_cards << '\n';
    std::cout << "Player 2 got: " << player2_cards << '\n';
}
```

in which case you don't use *any* loops and *any* index variables. This uses Eric Niebler's [ranges-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library. See also [this quick reference](https://www.walletfox.com/course/quickref_range_v3.php) to understand faster what's going on in this code if you're not familiar with the terms.

See this [<kbd>Live on GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/_ubD3d).